# Spring MVC - Getting NullPointerException of a Model Class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

The problem im facing is , when a customer tries to **add an item** to a cart , a **NullPointerException** is raised at Controller at this line of code

```
CustomerCart customercart = customer.getCustomercart();
```

Please check the Exception information

> xps_id : XPS00008  qty : 1 CUD00001 Apr 02, 2017 12:39:10 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path
>   [/TechNXT] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   technxt.controller.TechNXTCustomerController.addItemToCart(TechNXTCustomerController.java:150)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1354)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

So the **addItemToCart** is my Controller Method 
here is the Method

```
@RequestMapping("/customerreqAddItemToCart/{xps_id}")
    public String addItemToCart(@PathVariable("xps_id")String xps_id,@RequestParam("qty")int qty,Principal principal,HttpSession hsession,Model m){


        System.out.println("xps_id : "+xps_id + "  qty : " + qty);

        String customerid=principal.getName();
        System.out.println(customerid);
        Customer customer =cuss.getCustomerByUserId(customerid);
        CustomerCart customercart = customer.getCustomercart();
        Xmap_ps xmap_ps = xpss.getXPSbyId(xps_id);
        CustomerCartItems cartitem = new CustomerCartItems();

        cartitem.setCustomercart(customercart);
        cartitem.setXmap_ps(xmap_ps);
        cartitem.setCus_cartquantity(qty);  
        cartitem.setCus_cartitemwisetotal(xmap_ps.getXps_price()*qty);
        /*cartitem.setProduct_id(xmap_ps.getProduct_id());
        cartitem.setSupplier_id(xmap_ps.getSupplier_id());*/

        ccis.addCartItem(cartitem);

        Customer customer1=cuss.getCustomerByUserId(customerid);
        CustomerCart cart1=customer1.getCustomercart();

        int cartsize = ccss.getCartSize(cart1);

        List<CustomerCartItems> cartitems = cart1.getCustomercartitems();
        int sum=0;
        for(CustomerCartItems critem :cartitems){
            sum+= critem.getCus_cartitemwisetotal();
        }

        cart1.setCus_cartgrandtotal(sum);
        ccss.updateCart(cart1);         

        List<VwXmapPS> xpsdata = vxpss.getBestVwPs();

        m.addAttribute("xpsdata", xpsdata);

        m.addAttribute("customername",hsession.getAttribute("customername"));
        m.addAttribute("customerid",hsession.getAttribute("customerid"));
        m.addAttribute("cartsize",hsession.getAttribute("cartsize"));

        m.addAttribute("cartmessage","Item added to cart successfully");

        hsession.setAttribute("cartsize", cartsize);

        System.out.println("cart size :" + cartsize);       

        return "redirect:/reqdisplaycustomerhomepage";


    }
```

Let me also share my Model class with you all

> 1. ***CustomerCart*** Model class which has One to Many Relationship with ***CustomerCartItems*** Model class

```
@Entity
public class CustomerCart {

    @Id
    private String cus_cartid;
    private double cus_cartgrandtotal;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="customercart")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customercart", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<CustomerCartItems> customercartitems;
```

> 2. ***CustomerCartItems*** Model class

```
@Entity
public class CustomerCartItems {



    @Id
        private String cus_cartitemid;
        private int cus_cartquantity;
        private int cus_cartitemwisetotal;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="cus_cartid")
        private CustomerCart customercart;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="xps_id")
        private Xmap_ps xmap_ps;
```

> 3.And also The ***Customer*** Model Class which has all the Foreign Key relationship to other tables

```
 @Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private String cus_id;
    private String cus_name;
    private String cus_emailid;
    private String cus_mobileno;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="cus_loginid")
    private CustomerDetails customerdetails;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="cus_billingaddressid")
    private CustomerBillingAddress customerbillingaddress;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="cus_shippingaddressid")
    private CustomerShippingAddress customershippingaddress;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="cus_cartid")
    private CustomerCart customercart;
```

I dont think i made any kind of Error with my Model Class
And please let me know what else i can share with you all so that i can get a solution of it

Thank you for taking your time and Helping me <3

Comment: Sorry I gave the response based on the half code I saw. there is nothing to do with dependency injection If the nullpointer is coming at the line you showed in the top. more is looks like ` customer=cuss.getCustomerByUserId(customerid);` giving you null customer and it is resulting null pointer in the next line. Check the db and see if you are able to find Customer record for customerid.

Comment: @VijendraKulhade Sir , i am not getting Customerid as null .. here is the console result where i used to print the customerid   `psid : XPS00008  qty : 1
CUD00001`

Comment: @AyushAgarwal although `customerid` is not null, but most probably you dont have any `Customer` with that id in db as Vijendra Kulhade said. Thats why `customer=cuss.getCustomerByUserId(customerid);` is setting `customer` to null and throwing NPE from where you called `customer.getCustomercart();`

Comment: @minarmahmud no sir, Customer id is available in the Database !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this really do what you think it does?:

```
String customerid=principal.getName();
```

It don't think it gives you the `Id` field value that you have in the database.
You could store the logged in user's Id in the session or take it as a request parameter from the jsp.

debug it and you will see that `customer` is null.

Comment: yes the customerid is not from database , it is used with a help of httpsession which was giving me accurate customerid but , yea i found that the customer object of Customer table was retriving me null due to my service class ! debuged it and found ty ! ty so much for taking time and sorting the problem out !